# How does one determine the sample size and statistical analysis to be used?

Tags: sample-size

How does one determine the sample size and statistical analysis to be used for an experiment wherein there will be two interventions (no standard medicine for positive control) A and B, and the objective is to determine the effectiveness and viability of A and B on certain disease? There are 5 treatments: (1) disease no intervention (2) disease with intervention A (3) disease with intervention B (4) no disease no intervention (5) and maybe with disease with both interventions A and B.

Comment: What is the outcome variable and what values can it take on?  Are there other variables, besides treatment that can effect the outcome?  While this question seems rather simple, it is extremely complex and the answer is "it depends" on my different things.  It might be best to discuss your specific problem with a statistical consultant.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question, more information is needed. First, you need to have some estimate of effect size: How large an effect do you expect, or do you wish to be able to detect, statistically? I suggest taking a look at this information on power analysis:

[Quick-R Power Analysis](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/power.html)

In terms of the type of analysis to use, that depends entirely on the variables you're measuring and their values/distributions. It looks to me like you will be using a multi-way ANOVA, including interactions. You can use aov(), lm() or more complex functions as needed, assuming your data meets the required assumptions. You may need to look into non-parametric analyses as well.

We could probably help more if you provide more information on how you will be sampling. Will there be repeated measures on individuals? Will observations be nested inside individuals, or gender, etc.?

Comment: The subjects will be mice. I don't think repeated measures will be used in this thesis proposal. I really don't have a clue about sample sizes though. Anyway gender won't be affecting much I guess, but would it be better if the counts for each would be equal just to avoid a bias of some sort?
Effectiveness of the intervention would be qualitative assessment whether it resulted to either decrease or increase of the disease and quantitative according to the number of days it took to normalize the mice. I hope I don't give you a hard time.

Comment: Hi Brendan, the qualitative response is important to note, as is the fact that # of days is your quantitative response. You may want to look into logistic regression, or frequency analysis, since your qualitative response is binomial (better or not). However, that makes it a little difficult to determine effect size, and thus, sample size. If you choose frequency analysis (testing independence of treatment and response) you can use R to calculate sample size: pwr.chisq.test(w =, N = , df = , sig.level =, power = ). Check the link above to determine effect size in frequency analysis.